# Model Pipeline to run multiple Classifiers for ML Classification

Tags: python, machine-learning

As a general rule of thumb, it is required to run baseline models on the dataset. I know [H2O- AutoML](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o-tutorials/latest-stable/h2o-world-2017/automl/index.html) and other AutoML packages do this. But I want to try using Scikit-learn Pipeline,

Here is what I have done so far,

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import os
rs = {'random_state': 42}
```

```
# Train-test Split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, 
                                                    y, 
                                                    test_size = 0.33, 
                                                    random_state = 42)
```

```
# Classification - Model Pipeline
def modelPipeline(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):

    log_reg = LogisticRegression(**rs)
    nb = BernoulliNB()
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
    svm = SVC(**rs)
    mlp = MLPClassifier(max_iter=500, **rs)
    dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(**rs)
    et = ExtraTreesClassifier(**rs)
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(**rs)
    xgb = XGBClassifier(**rs, verbosity=0)

    clfs = [
            ('Logistic Regression', log_reg), 
            ('Naive Bayes', nb),
            ('K-Nearest Neighbors', knn), 
            ('SVM', svm), 
            ('MLP', mlp), 
            ('Decision Tree', dt), 
            ('Extra Trees', et), 
            ('Random Forest', rf), 
            ('XGBoost', xgb)
            ]


    pipelines = []

    scores_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Model', 'F1_Score', 'Precision', 'Recall', 'Accuracy', 'ROC_AUC'])


    for clf_name, clf in clfs:

        pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
                                   ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
                                   ('classifier', clf)
                                   ]
                            )
        pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)


        y_pred = pipeline.predict(X_test)
        # F1-Score
        fscore = skm.f1_score(y_test, y_pred)
        # Precision
        pres = skm.precision_score(y_test, y_pred)
        # Recall
        rcall = skm.recall_score(y_test, y_pred)
        # Accuracy
        accu = skm.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
        # ROC_AUC
        roc_auc = skm.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)


        pipelines.append(pipeline)

        scores_df = scores_df.append({
                                      'Model' : clf_name, 
                                      'F1_Score' : fscore,
                                      'Precision' : pres,
                                      'Recall' : rcall,
                                      'Accuracy' : accu,
                                      'ROC_AUC' : roc_auc
                                      
                                      }, 
                                     ignore_index=True)
        
    return pipelines, scores_df
```

I have a nagging feeling that there's something I might be overlooking, or missing, or that there might be a more efficient way to do this.

Is there a better / more elegant / more accurate way to run multiple classifiers for ML classification?
Efficiency is also good, though we never call this on large datasets, it is not a huge concern.